# Can we find $\lambda$ s.t. $e^{\lambda t}(\lambda u(t,x)+g(u(t,x))\ge0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

Let $T>0$, $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open, $u\in C([0,T]\times\overline\Omega)\cap C^{1,\:2}((0,T)\cap\overline\Omega)$ be nonnegative and $g\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ with $g(0)=0$. Can we choose $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that $$e^{\lambda t}(\lambda u(t,x)+g(u(t,x))\ge0\tag1$$ for all $(t,x)\in(0,T)\times\Omega$?

Intuitively, this should be true. If $u(t,x)=0$, then (since $g(0)=0$) $(1)$ trivially holds. Moreover, $c:=\inf_{(0,\:T)\times\Omega}(g\circ u)>-\infty$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$u$ is bounded because it is continuous on a compact set. Suppose $|u(t,x)| \leq M$. Note that $g'$ is continuous, hence bounded on $[-M,M]$. Suppose $|g'| \leq \lambda$  on $[-M,M]$ . Then MVT give $|g(x)|=|g(x)-g(0)| \leq \lambda |x|$. Hence, $\lambda u(t,x)+g(u(t,x)) \geq \lambda u(t,x)-\lambda u(t,x) = 0$.